# Tex file in binary

Tags: texmaker, unicode, input-encodings

My machine was powered down after it was frozen, but I still managed to save the current Latex file. When I turned the machine back on and tried to import the file in texmaker , I was given this message:

`It seems taht this file cannot be correctly decoded with the default encoding setting (UTF-8)`

Moreover, I looked at the file's charset using the `file -bi name_of_file` in my command line, and I got that the file's charset is binary. I tried the `iconv` utility in linux to try convert it to utf-8 charset but it didn't work as the binary charset is not supported by `iconv`. Is there any way I can save this file? I really need its contents.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to edit or copy & paste in `gedit`, and then sava copy with  "Save as" taking care of the options (encoding and the type of end of line). Check that is not a corrupted file (no lost text, no unexpected characters). In the worse case, `testdisk` could be useful.

Comment: Just open the file in a editor that opens binary file. In windows, I would have used notepad++. Then it is just to copy and paste out the readable content, search for rubbish and replace with what should have been there. Of course, if the file is toatally destroyed (just full of strange charackters, @@@@@@&&&---'///" etc), nothing will help other than a fresh backup.

Comment: @Fran You were faster than me!

Comment: Are there any news to report?